# fluentbit configmap logs distribution as per namespace

Tags: regex, kubernetes, devops, fluent-bit

Scenario:- I have fluent bit configmap, which helps to send container logs to ES as per their namespaces.

Problem:- When I started we have 3 to 4 namespaces and I make the changes manually in my fluent bit config map and applied it. but now we have currently 20+ namespaces and they are keep on increasing. So want to use regex or any better alternative to solve this updating issue which making my fluent bit configmap file making exceptionally large.

Below is my "sample" configmap file with only 3 namespaces :-

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: fluent-bit-config
  namespace: logging
  labels:
    k8s-app: fluent-bit
data:
  # Configuration files: server, input, filters and output
  # ======================================================
  fluent-bit.conf: |
    [SERVICE]
        Flush         1
        Log_Level     info
        Daemon        off
        Parsers_File  parsers.conf
        HTTP_Server   On
        HTTP_Listen   0.0.0.0
        HTTP_Port     2020
    @INCLUDE input-kubernetes.conf
    @INCLUDE filter-kubernetes.conf
    @INCLUDE output-elasticsearch.conf
  input-kubernetes.conf: |
    [INPUT]
        Name              tail
        Tag               kube.ns1.*
        Path              /var/log/containers/*ns1*.log
        Parser            docker
        DB                /var/log/ns1.db
        Mem_Buf_Limit     10MB
        Skip_Long_Lines   On
        Refresh_Interval  10
    [INPUT]
        Name              tail
        Tag               kube.ns2.*
        Path              /var/log/containers/*ns2*.log
        Parser            docker
        DB                /var/log/ns2.db
        Mem_Buf_Limit     10MB
        Skip_Long_Lines   On
        Refresh_Interval  10
    [INPUT]
        Name              tail
        Tag               kube.ns3.*
        Path              /var/log/containers/*ns3*.log
        Parser            docker
        DB                /var/log/ns3.db
        Mem_Buf_Limit     10MB
        Skip_Long_Lines   On
        Refresh_Interval  10
   
  filter-kubernetes.conf: |
    [FILTER]
        Name                kubernetes
        Match               kube.*
        Kube_URL            https://kubernetes.default.svc:443
        Kube_CA_File        /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
        Kube_Token_File     /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token
        Kube_Tag_Prefix     kube.var.log.containers.
        Merge_Log           On
        Merge_Log_Key       log_processed
        K8S-Logging.Parser  On
        K8S-Logging.Exclude Off
    [FILTER]
        Name                kubernetes2
        Match               kube2.*
        Kube_URL            https://kubernetes.default.svc:443
        Kube_CA_File        /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
        Kube_Token_File     /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token
        Kube_Tag_Prefix     kube.var.log.containers.
        Merge_Log           On
        K8S-Logging.Parser  On
        K8S-Logging.Exclude Off
        Keep_Log            Off
  output-elasticsearch.conf: |
    [OUTPUT]
        Name            es
        Match           kube.ns1.*
        Host            ${FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_HOST}
        Port            ${FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PORT}
        Logstash_Format On
        Logstash_Prefix ns1
        Time_Key        @timestamp
        tls             On
        Retry_Limit     False
    [OUTPUT]
        Name            es
        Match           kube.ns2.*
        Host            ${FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_HOST}
        Port            ${FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PORT}
        Logstash_Format On
        Logstash_Prefix ns2
        Time_Key        @timestamp
        tls             On
        Retry_Limit     False
    [OUTPUT]
        Name            es
        Match           kube.ns3.*
        Host            ${FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_HOST}
        Port            ${FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PORT}
        Logstash_Format On
        Logstash_Prefix ns4
        Time_Key        @timestamp
        tls             On
        Retry_Limit     False

  parsers.conf: |
    [PARSER]
        Name   apache
        Format regex
        Regex  ^(?<host>[^ ]*) [^ ]* (?<user>[^ ]*) \[(?<time>[^\]]*)\] "(?<method>\S+)(?: +(?<path>[^\"]*?)(?: +\S*)?)?" (?<code>[^ ]*) (?<size>[^ ]*)(?: "(?<referer>[^\"]*)" "(?<agent>[^\"]*)")?$
        Time_Key time
        Time_Format %d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z
    [PARSER]
        Name   apache2
        Format regex
        Regex  ^(?<host>[^ ]*) [^ ]* (?<user>[^ ]*) \[(?<time>[^\]]*)\] "(?<method>\S+)(?: +(?<path>[^ ]*) +\S*)?" (?<code>[^ ]*) (?<size>[^ ]*)(?: "(?<referer>[^\"]*)" "(?<agent>[^\"]*)")?$
        Time_Key time
        Time_Format %d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z
    [PARSER]
        Name   apache_error
        Format regex
        Regex  ^\[[^ ]* (?<time>[^\]]*)\] \[(?<level>[^\]]*)\](?: \[pid (?<pid>[^\]]*)\])?( \[client (?<client>[^\]]*)\])? (?<message>.*)$
    [PARSER]
        Name   nginx
        Format regex
        Regex ^(?<remote>[^ ]*) (?<host>[^ ]*) (?<user>[^ ]*) \[(?<time>[^\]]*)\] "(?<method>\S+)(?: +(?<path>[^\"]*?)(?: +\S*)?)?" (?<code>[^ ]*) (?<size>[^ ]*)(?: "(?<referer>[^\"]*)" "(?<agent>[^\"]*)")?$
        Time_Key time
        Time_Format %d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z
    [PARSER]
        Name   json
        Format json
        Time_Key time
        Time_Format %d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z
    [PARSER]
        Name        docker
        Format      json
        Time_Key    time
        Time_Format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L
        Time_Keep   On
    [PARSER]
        Name        syslog
        Format      regex
        Regex       ^\<(?<pri>[0-9]+)\>(?<time>[^ ]* {1,2}[^ ]* [^ ]*) (?<host>[^ ]*) (?<ident>[a-zA-Z0-9_\/\.\-]*)(?:\[(?<pid>[0-9]+)\])?(?:[^\:]*\:)? *(?<message>.*)$
        Time_Key    time
        Time_Format %b %d %H:%M:%S
    [PARSER]
        Name    kube-custom
        Format  regex
        Regex   (?<tag>[^.]+)?\.?(?<pod_name>[a-z0-9](?:[-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?(?:\.[a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?)*)_(?<namespace_name>[^_]+)_(?<container_name>.+)-(?<docker_id>[a-z0-9]{64})\.log$
```

Comment: Did you solve it later？thanks